# DLL gives Abnormal program termination on creating ADO object

Tags: dll, com, ado, c++builder

I have a few datamodules, created with C++ Builder 6. Each of them uses another datamodule that initializes the connection with the database. I'm trying to make a DLL out of those datamodules.

The error is thrown on creation of DataModule_Users and says 'Abnormal program termination'.

Where do I go wrong?

Thanks in advance

**datamodule_dll.bpf**

```
USEFORM("DataModule_Connection.cpp", DataModule_Connection); /* TDataModule: File Type */
USEFORM("DataModule_Users.cpp", DataModule_Users); /*TDataModule: File Type */
//------------------------------------------------------------------
This file is used by the project manager only and should be treated like the project file

DllEntryPoint
```

**datamodule_DLL.cpp**

```
int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
  return 1;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char * GetUserName(const char * ID);

const char * GetUserName(const char * ID) {
  CoInitialize(NULL); // datasets use COM
  // This is used by DataModule_Users (normally this is done with Application->CreateForm();
  DataModule_Connection = new DataModule_Connection( 0 /* Owner */ );
  DataModule_Users = new DataModule_Users( 0 /* Owner */ );
  return DataModule_Users->GetUserName(ID);
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code to see why it is crashing? Also, you are creating new DataModule objects every time GetUserName() is called, but you are not freeing them.  And you should not be calling CoInitialize() at all.  You are setting the COM apartment model for the caller, which may be the completely wrong thing to do, or using the wrong model, etc. If you really need to control the COM apartment model inside the DLL then move the DataModules to their own worker thread.

Comment: If I remove the CoInitialize, i get the error 'CoInitialize has not been called'. I wanted to create the datamodules in DllEntryPoint(), but those give errors too. So I've wrapped them in an if-structure to create them only once.

Comment: COM is initialized on a per-thread basis. Once a thread's COM model (apartment vs multithreaded) has been set, it cannot be changed later. If your DLL calls CoInitialize() before the caller does, your parameters would take priority, which might not meet the caller's needs. If you want to control the COM settings for your DMs without affecting the caller, you have to move the DMs to their own thread. Besides, DllEntryPoint() is not an appropriate place to initialize them anyway. The OS restricts what DllEntryPoint() is allowed to do.

Comment: You are totally right. it works now. I call coInitialize() before I load the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will quote Remy Lebeau:

> COM is initialized on a per-thread basis. Once a thread's COM model
>   (apartment vs multithreaded) has been set, it cannot be changed later.
>   If your DLL calls CoInitialize() before the caller does, your
>   parameters would take priority, which might not meet the caller's
>   needs. If you want to control the COM settings for your DMs without
>   affecting the caller, you have to move the DMs to their own thread.
>   Besides, DllEntryPoint() is not an appropriate place to initialize
>   them anyway. The OS restricts what DllEntryPoint() is allowed to do.

This solved the issue. I had to call coInitialize() before I load the library.